# Apply border without distorting page layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I'm trying to apply a "border" (blue, 2px width) to certain elements (div/images/etc.) on a web page, after the entire page has loaded, via Javascript.

However, when I do so for some elements, some parts of the page layout (nearby that element) is distorted. It seems that is because the browser would repaint the layout which may change after application of the border.

Is there a way to do this without having the rest of the layout being distorted? 
(note that this needs to work across various pages on my website, in a generic way)

Comment: Hi, please show us what you have done?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `box-sizing` property controls whether or not the border (and padding) are counted as part of the element's size. Setting `box-sizing: border-box;` should yield the behavior you're looking for. [Here's a great article on the topic](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)